# How to store number of clicks/ day for a longer period?

Tags: mysql, statistics, store

I need to store some stats: the number of clicks on some items (more than 1000 items).
I need to store the clicks daily:
e.g: day 1: 1234 clicks on item 1
day 2: 12312 clicks on item 1
day n: 13123  clicks on item 1

I have a cheap server so I need an optimal way to store all this data. Later I need to generate charts from this data

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store individuals click in database on daily basis, next day run cron job what will generate summary reports, store (much smaller) results in other tables, clean raw data from previous day...

EDIT:
if you want only monitor click per item per day logical structure would be:

```
raport_date - date
item_id     - reference to table stored info about items
hits        - number of calculated hits
```

everything depends what reports / charts you would need

Comment: Thanks, but I have 1 more question: how should I design this another table for best performances ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a table with 3 columns (you can add a primary column in addition if you'd like).

I see you as needing the following:

1. A column named, say, "day", with a type of DateTime
2. A column named, say, "itemId", with type of Int, which is how you'll know what item was clicked
3. A column named, say, "clicks", with a type of Int, which will be your counter

So lets say our table was named, "clickTracking".

You can do, "insert into clickTracking set day = date_format(now(),"%Y-%m-%d"), itemId = 1, clicks = clicks + 1 on duplicate key update clicks = clicks + 1;"

I've attached some example mySQL below, with a primary key. I find the data easier to work with, if I have an auto_increment field, but it is not a requirement.

```
mysql> create table clickTracking (id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,day datetime not null, itemId int unsigned not null, clicks int unsigned not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create unique index item on clickTracking (day,itemId);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into clickTracking set day = date_format(now(),"%Y-%m-%d"), itemId = 1, clicks = clicks + 1 on duplicate key update clicks = clicks + 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into clickTracking set day = date_format(now(),"%Y-%m-%d"), itemId = 1, clicks = clicks + 1 on duplicate key update clicks = clicks + 1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into clickTracking set day = date_format(now(),"%Y-%m-%d"), itemId = 1, clicks = clicks + 1 on duplicate key update clicks = clicks + 1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into clickTracking set day = date_format(now(),"%Y-%m-%d"), itemId = 2, clicks = clicks + 1 on duplicate key update clicks = clicks + 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from clickTracking;
+----+---------------------+--------+--------+
| id | day                 | itemId | clicks |
+----+---------------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | 2011-03-20 00:00:00 |      1 |      3 |
|  2 | 2011-03-20 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |
+----+---------------------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are quiet a few ways to do this. I've provided one possible solution. I prefer this method, because it makes reports easy to make, and has a minimal amount of storage on the server.

I would recommend making an additional table of "items", that corresponds to the itemId here.